# how to search a List<list<int>> with another List<int> in c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following lists of list.

```
List<List<int>> paths = new List<List<int>>();
paths.Add(new List<int>() { 0,1 });
paths.Add(new List<int>() { 0, 2 });
paths.Add(new List<int>() { 0, 4 });
paths.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 2 });
paths.Add(new List<int>() { 0, 3 });
```

and I have another List of int like this

```
List<int> ends = new List<int>(){3,4};
```

Now I need to filter records where any number in the inner list in paths contains any numbers from the ends list, which for this example would be the following records.

```
{0,3}
{0,4}
```

I tried something like this

```
paths.Where(x => x.Where(y => ends.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Comment: you need to look at all elements of y

Comment: `paths.Where(x => x.Any(_=> ends.Contains(_))).ToList()`

Comment: Do the inner lists always consist of precisely two elements? E.g. do these represent coordinates or edges in a graph perhaps? If so, you might find a tuple or a two-field class to be a useful alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 paths.Where(x => x.Any(z => ends.Contains(z)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any` to solve your problem:

```cs
var res = paths.Where(list => list.Any(item => ends.Any(end => end==item))).ToList();
```

or shorter

```cs
var res = paths.Where(list => list.Any(item => ends.Contains(item))).ToList();
```

Result:

[image: Result in LinqPad]

Answer (score 0):

LINQ syntax would be an expressive alternative for this:

```cs
var matches = (from p in paths
               from e in ends
               where p.Contains(e)
               select p).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var paths = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new List<int>() { 0, 1 },
            new List<int>() { 0, 2 },
            new List<int>() { 0, 4 },
            new List<int>() { 1, 2 },
            new List<int>() { 0, 3 }
        };

        var ends = new List<int>(){3,4};
        var results = paths.Where(x => ends.Any(x.Contains));
        
        // display results
        foreach(var result in results)
            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));
    }
}

//[0,4]
//[0,3]
```